# What is the best approach to this situation?

Tags: middlegame

[image]

So I am still learning chess and I have a lot of trouble in these situations. Please help me with what to do in the next few turns.

Comment: As you are a beginner I don't really want to say this, but I have to be honest: Black is totally lost. I would resign and get on with learning something new from the next game rather than struggling on in a hopeless position. If you want more feedback I suggest showing the whole game

Comment: Please do not ask questions on ongoing games

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are a queen and a piece down. Your position is completely hopeless. Your best move here is to resign the game.

It's not clear how well your opponent has played to reach this position but you have clearly played very badly indeed. An opponent who was good enough to reach this position is going to finish you off very quickly regardless of what you do.

As a beginner you need to start by learning about opening principles, tactics and simple endgames. If you use the search function in this forum you will find many questions and answers that can help you with these.

Comment: If this position was reached, tactics should probably be #1 priority